# Sequelize "WHERE" Clause in subqueries

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, backend

I'am trying to build my query using sequelize, in the where clause I need to give the conditional value from my front-end so i did it like this :

```
getResults(req) {
            return parm
                .findAll({
                    attributes: [
                        sequelize.literal('DISTINCT "id"')
                    ],
                    where :  {
                        name: req.query.parm.replace(/"/g, '').split(',')
                    } ,            
                    raw: true
                });

        }
```

and it's working!
but now I need to write a subquery including where clause:
something like this :

```
SELECT tab1.name FROM
(SELECT name FROM "MYTABLE"
WHERE id = (value from the front-end) AND name IN (values from front-end)
) as tab1
```

Here is what i have tried :

```
    getTest(req) { 
if (req.query.parm != null) {
 return parm .sequelize.query('SELECT id FROM "table_base" where id = $mid ); ',
 { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT , 
   bind: { mid: [req.query.parm.replace(/"/g, '').split(',')] }} ); 
} 
},
```

i tried to use raw query and i tested the binding parameters but i get this error when i execute this testing query :

```
Executing (default): SELECT id FROM "table_base" where id = $1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is YES it is indeed possible! SQL can pretty much do anything even if you are using sequelize. If you write the subquery and it doesn't work just post it back here so people can take a look and debug. Thanks

Comment: i tried to use raw query and i tested the binding parameters but i get this error when i execute this testing query :  Executing (default): SELECT id FROM  "table_base" where  id = $1 );                    
     getTest(req) {
        if (req.query.parm != null) {
            return parm
                .sequelize.query('SELECT id FROM  "table_base"  where id = $mid ); ',
                { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT ,
                bind: { mid: [req.query.parm.replace(/"/g, '').split(',')] }}
                );
        }
    },

Comment: Hey can you add your SQL script to the question just saying something like here's what i have tried :)